# OCCI - Connecting to a remote database

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

I'm fairly new to Oracle. I'm trying to connect to a remote Oracle database using OCCI. All the examples i've found up this point have been for connecting to a local database. Could someone please point me in the right direction and let me know where i can find an example connection to get me past this point? Thanks, Mike

Comment: There's nothing different, when you're trying to connect to remote DB and to a local on. What connection string you use for connecting? Or you just use the service name? Or you're not able to connect to any DB ? And do you have remote DB, with real user/pass, IP and port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
createConnection( "name", "passwrd", "string")
```

["string" stands either for the connection name that is resolved with the Oracle "tnsnames.ora" file which should be located in your ORACLE_HOME(Oracle install dir)\NETWORK\ADMIN directory or for a connection string like below](http://www.dbforums.com/oracle/1607236-occi-connection-string.html)

```
Code:
connection_name =
  (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ip_address)(PORT = listener_port))
       (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME = listener_service_name)
       (SERVER = DEDICATED))
 )
```

Comment: It's not necessary you have such file. You can you full connection string (instead of just service name + tnsnames.ora ) and then there must be such file on the server. Also, to use it like this, you need to have TNS_ADMIN, which points to the same location, where ORACLE_HOME points. That's why I asked all the questions in my comment.

Comment: @Kiril Kirov - By the OPs question I believed he has difficulty with connecting to any non local machine, so I posted him an answer to kick off atleast. I would be happy to delete it should he gets no help from the answer.

Comment: no, there's no need to delete anything, it's useful, well-formatted and **right** answer, no matter if this will help the OP or not :)

Comment: Hey guys thanks for response, so is this what i would set in my code as for the connection_name and pass that string to the createconnection method call?

Comment: Hey thank coder, i just gave that a try in my code and it worked. Thanks for to you and Kiril for taking the time to clarify for me. Much appreciated.